# Change of coordinates in P3 with p(2)=0.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Let V = {p(t) ∈ $P_3$ | p(2) = 0}. V has bases B = {$t-2$, $(t-2)^2$, $(t-2)^3$} and C = {$t-2$, $t^2-2t$, $t^3-2t^2$}. Find the change of coordinates matrices from B to C and from C to B.

The only thing that is throwing me off is the p(2)=0 part. I don't know how to account for that constraint.

Comment: I don’t think that you really have to worry about that part since you’ve been given two bases for the space already.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Express elements of  $B$ in terms of elements of $C$ and vice-versa. The coefficients will give you the change of coordinates matrices.